# How to hide the close button and close action in alert view to display only "Open app" button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I have implemented `UIlocalNotification` method using the link

[Adding Local Notifications With iOS 4](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/07/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html)

in my app my requirement is that

in notification alert we need to have only `"Show me"` button which opens the app by default,

we need to force the user to open the app when notification , So there must no close button in the notification alert.

only one button that too Show me must opent the app

how?

Comment: Even if this were possible, I doubt this would get accepted on the App Store. An unignorable notification that forced the user into an app? It would get rejected from my phone pretty quickly too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not want to show the alert action button you can disable it by setting the `hasAction` property to `NO`.
    Note that without the action button there is no option for the user to launch the application from the alert.
    (If you do not want to see the alert at all you should set `alertBody` to `nil`.)

**EDIT:**

- You can not remove cancel button.
- You have only option to remove action button not cancel button and As
  it is defined in implementation file of `UILocalNotification` so u can
  not override it.

Comment: It's possible to disable only the action button, not the cancel button. Your extract talks about the action button

Comment: that's why i had added that link. I have edited my answer now. You can not remove cancel button.

Comment: How can I add some action on button "View". When I get local notification and presses the button "View" it opens the app and that  is fine but what should I do if I want to perform some action on the button "View"? Please help me...

Comment: @ManthanPatel For that you need to add these methods in your app delegate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140055/not-receiving-any-push-notification-in-iphone/16140565#16140565

Comment: I haven't been able to make `hasAction = NO` work neither in iOS 5, not iOS 6, nor iOS 7. The button is always shown. Has the behaviour been changed?

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove the cancel button.

Few more things are there:

- If the phone is locked means the user can't see any buttons(a swipe button appears to perform ur `showme` function).
- If the user changed the settings for notification to other than alert
  type, the user can't even see the `UIAlertView`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your view conforms to UIAlertViewDelegate protocol:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

When you want the alert to show, do this:

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Show me" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

If you want to do something when the button is clicked, implement this

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;{
// the user clicked OK
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
    //do something here...
}
}
```

Comment: He is talking about local notification, not UIAlertView