# iOS push notifications using TLS certificate vs. using authentication tokens

Tags: ios, push-notification, token, tls1.2

I am reading the documentation for both [push using TLS certificates](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev11b059073?sub=dev73a37248c) and [push using authentication tokens](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev54d690a66?sub=dev73a37248c)

But besides explaining how to configure each, the articles don't really explain the differences or pros/cons of both approaches. Can somebody explain them to me?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Token-based authentication is newer and essentially simplifies APNS authentication. 
It is based on a public and private key pair that you can generate on your Apple developer account.

Here are the main reasons why it is simpler:

- The same key can be used for development and production apps whereas
  different certificates are needed when using certificate-based
  authentication.
- The same key is used for all your apps referenced in    your Apple
  developer account. Certificate-based authentication needs    one
  certificate per app.
- The key does not expire. Certificates do expire and need to be renewed every year or so.

A good source of intel is the 2016 WWDC video regarding APNS:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/724/

Comment: Am I crazy or does the new token based approach seem way less secure. Being unable to separate out your production and development environments seems like a problem.

Answer (score 8):

For 2020, you can only realistically use the "token" method.  The older approach is legacy and they will probably axe it.

Your **private key** will look like this

```
let keystring = `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49Aas8d76as8das687asd687asd68as8brwUIWA46qcXis
zCu6dbd4s8d7b5s86gf98ugtr28re7089a7d6tbvpiiui524kyfpq9861eFJP7we
eE7rX4182609457ohgyj3lhgp98wfb698bfg69287f2k4htgwpo876grwo7XDklz
9fdg689d
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`
```

your **key id** will look like this

```
let keyId = "CTU7XXBPRH"
```

and your Apple team id is your usual Apple team id, which looks like  "YWD3UUTEWD".

Nowadays - thank goodness - it is relatively easy to get the private key and key id from inside your company's account on the Apple developer website.

If you want to test sending a push on an ordinary Node server on AWS, I strongly recommend this outstanding new npm, APNS2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/apns2

```
let bn = new BasicNotification(deviceToken, 'Hello')
```

It's about that easy to send pushes.

Tips:

**Don't forget the damned "development/sandbox" pushes only work ON AN IPHONE TETHERED TO YOUR MAC/XCODE!**

- development/sandbox pushes - only for an iPhone ***tethered to your Mac*** with a build running from Xcode
- **production** pushes - ***they do work completely fine with ***TestFlight*** builds***.

Additionally: don't forget that the so-called development/sandbox pushes are often flakey.  Often, they don't arrive for hours, they don't arrive at all, they simply don't work in many regions.

Don't forget that it is TOTALLY OK to use the ***"production"*** ones, simply, with a ***TestFlight*** app.

So

1. Make a build
2. Push it to your TestFlight account. Wait a few minutes as usual until the build comes through,
3. Install it ***from TestFlight*** to your phone
4. You ***will*** now get ***all*** the pushes - instantly!

Whereas if you

1. Make a build
2. Just build/run to your ***tethered*** iPhone
3. You do ***NOT*** get any pushes.
4. It's true that you can get the so-called "development" pushes, but they are often **very flakey**.

(To be clear, when using APNS2, if you do want to try "development" pushes, to order "development" pushes, simply use the extra line of code explained at the bottom here https://www.npmjs.com/package/apns2 )

Comment: "he older approach is legacy and they will probably axe it." Can you please provide any link when this is made official by Apple? 

According the Apple Developer documentation, certificate based authentication is still a valid technique:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_certificate-based_connection_to_apns

Answer (score 7):

In 2021, Apple's [Setting Up a Remote Notification Server](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server) state

> **Both techniques have advantages and disadvantages**, so decide which technique is best for your company.

Both Fattie and Ika have said that TLS/ Certificate based authentication is inferior. The [Project UI in Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/) also uses language which doesn't explain much IMHO:

> Configuration with auth keys is **recommended** as they are the more current method for sending notifications to iOS

## Benefits of [Certificate Authentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_certificate-based_connection_to_apns)

- **Limited access certificates.** Each certificate is tied to one application in your developer account and environment (development/ production). This avoids putting all your eggs in one basket, if your token auth key is compromised, a threat actor can push notifications to all your applications.
- **Simpler Provider application logic.** The provider (service which interacts with APNs) (either your own server or a service you use) can just use the TLS certificate, and authenticate, without needing to create JWTs, add headers to the request or find the correct App ID to use.

## Benefits of [Token Authentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns)

- **Simpler setup process:** because you only have to download a `.p12` and use it your application. Go into developer.apple.com, create a Push Notification Key. However, your application has to renew these tokens every hour. Creating a `.p12` for TLS authentication is a little bit more involved.
- **Does not expire**, so you can set it and forget it. Whereas TLS certificates expire in 1 year by default.

---

## The question boils down to security vs. convenience.

- Convenience (use token auth): It's convenient to create a key and forget (token auth), and you might use Firebase (or another service) to actually renew the tokens every hour, so you don't have much work to do.
- Security (use TLS auth): Do you really want to share the same key between all your applications? What if you want to limit the scope of a Push Notification Service Provider (e.g. Firebase, Ably, Pusher), but don't trust giving them access to all your applications. In reality, you might just have 1 application, so it does not matter.

Does this kind of even security matter, or is it just more convenient to use Token Auth? I would say in most cases, go with Token auth.