# Buttons on UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have an app in which I want to make the user make a judgement from 1 - 4. I am using a UIAlertView:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Judgment" message:@"Please choose your overall judgement." delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"1",  @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];
```

Although it works the view looks like the one shown below, with the number 4 where the Cancel button usually is. Is there a better way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: what does it look like when you do add a cancel button?

Comment: Worse - the text goes into an text box type field (white background) as always happens for some reason when you add them and the top button is over the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always modify your alert view by subclassing it. Not the easiest thing in the world, but I don't know of another way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

This link shows how to make the alert view look however you want it to.
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics/

Comment: Thank you. I thought that may have been the answer but have been putting off trying to work it out. The tutorial is perfect and exactly what I have been looking for. Brilliant!!

Answer (score 0):

You should set the button index of cancel button to -1:

```
alert.cancelButtonIndex = -1;
```

As the Doc say about the `cancelButtonIndex`:

```
The button indices start at 0. If -1, then the index is not set.
```

Comment: Thanks but it still appears exactly the same with the 4 lower than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

[How to hide the close button and close action in alert view to display only "Open app" buttom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355169/how-to-hide-the-close-button-and-close-action-in-alert-view-to-display-only-ope). According the answers, it's not possible to hide the cancel button. But it's worth it check it out.

Hope it helps